# Obter posição de links em um menu usando jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando pegar a posição dos links de um menu e não estou conseguindo

```
<nav class="menu">      
    <ul class="nav">
        <!-- <span><a href=""><img src="cds.jgp" alt="Logo Cetec"></a></span> -->
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#servicos">Serviços</a></li>
        <li><a href="#empresa">Empresa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#clientes">Clientes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#social">Social</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#comentarios">Comentários</a></li>         
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Usando o jQuery

```
$('a').click(function(){ return false; });
$('.nav li a').click(function(){
    //$('.nav li a').removeClass('active');
    //$(this).addClass('active');
    var getlink = $(this).attr("href");
    var getpos  = $(getlink).position().top;        
    console.log(getpos);
    return false;
});
```

No console só aparece essa mensagem

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, você está passando o conteúdo do atributo href para o seletor do jQuery, logo ele não consegue localizar o elemento.

O que está acontecendo:

```
var getlink = $(this).attr("href");
```

A variável getlink tem nela por exemplo: http://www.example.com
e quando você realiza:

```
var getpos  = $(getlink).position().top;
```

O jQuery recebe:

```
var getpos  = $('http://www.example.com').position().top;
```

Por esse motivo ele não consegue localizar nenhum elemento para receber a função chamada.

Basta alterar para:

```
var getpos  = $(this).position().top;
```

Corrigido:

```
$('a').click(function(){ return false; });
$('.nav li a').click(function(){
    //$('.nav li a').removeClass('active');
    //$(this).addClass('active');
    var getlink = $(this).attr("href");
    var getpos  = $(this).position().top;        
    console.log(getpos);
    return false;
});
```

**Exemplo JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/mbpcZ/

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo aqui... Vlw!

Answer (score 0):

Nos códigos que apresentou não há uso do JQuery UI, mas somente do JQuery.

**Fazendo uma correção no script**

Original:

```
$('a').click(function(){ return false; });
$('.nav li a').click(function(){
    //$('.nav li a').removeClass('active');
    //$(this).addClass('active');
    var getlink = $(this).attr("href");
    var getpos  = $(getlink).position().top;        
    console.log(getpos);
    return false;
});
```

Correção sugerida:

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav li a').click(function(){
        var getpos  = $(this).offset();
        console.log(getpos);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Removi o trecho

```
$('a').click(function(){ return false; });
```

O motivo é que o retorno "false" já está definida para $('.nav li a')
Ao aplicar para $('a'), todos os objetos, mesmo fora do menu, retornarão falso parao evento de click()

**Uso de event handler**

Para o caso do objeto alvo estar dentro de outro objeto cuja dimensões sejam maiores, com finalidade de obter maior precisão sobre qual objeto foi realmente clicado, utilize o event handler. 
Exemplo:

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav li a').click(function(e){
        var getpos  = $(e.target).offset();
        console.log(getpos);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Leia a documentação: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Daniel, Obrigado por responder. Eu consegui pegar a posição usando seu condigo, so que não consegui pegar os valores dos links, na verdade eu preciso pegar os valores do links do menu, no caso os hrefs, depois pegar a posição TOP desses hrefs para poder fazer uma navegação animada.

Comment: Nesse caso é outro assunto.
Sem mais delongas, basta usar o método attr()

Exemplo:

link = $(this).attr('href');